# SQL Slow Loading Time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the below code and it loads fine when there are only a few `follower_id` or `username` in the table `tblfollowers`.
But as soon as it gets into the thousands, it loads really slowly.
Is there a better way to write this?

I added indexes on the fields it joins on and that doesnt seem to make a difference.

```
$scheduler->render_table("events 
    LEFT JOIN tblfollowers ON events.id_user = tblfollowers.username 
    WHERE events.status ='active' 
      AND((tblfollowers.follower_id)='$test') OR ((events.id_user) ='$test') 
    GROUP BY events.event_id, events.event_name, events.user_name, events.id_user, events.time, events.details, events.location, events.dresscode 
    ORDER BY events.timestamp DESC"
  ,"event_id","start_date, start_date,event_name,details");
$scheduler->render_sql("SELECT event_id, start_date, end_date, event_name, details 
                        FROM events ");
```

Here's the explain for this query:

```
1 SIMPLE events ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 1593 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort    
1 SIMPLE tblfollowers ref PRIMARY PRIMARY   
4 dbhappps.events.id_user 17 Using where; Using index
```

**Here are the tables**

> Blockquote

**Table Events:**

```
event_id   int(11)  Primary Unique Index    
event_name varchar(400) 
user_name  varchar(155)  
id_user int(11)  Primary Unique  Index
start_date datetime
end_date  datetime   
details varchar(700)
location varchar(255)
dresscode varchar(255)
timestamp timestamp on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

> Blockquote

**tblfollowers:**

```
username int(11) primary
follower_id int(11) primary
timestamp timestamp on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

**How do I speed this query up?**

Comment: Can you better explain your table schema.  Specifically, provide information on your indexes.

Comment: @MikeBrant There are no indexes on the table. At one point I had an index on the id_user and event_id but as you see below the answer says that indexes would slow upload time.  If you look at the very bottom I did and EXPLAIN SELECT on the query so you can see the results of that

Comment: Without your index you are doing full table scans. Yes indexes will add to load time, but that's the price you pay. Also look at "(tblfollowers.follower_id)='$test') OR ((events.id_user) ='$test')". Might it not be better to move id_user check to a where clause?

Comment: Why are you doing a `left join` instead of an `inner join`?

Comment: @johan using an inner join or left join has no impact on the speed of the query.

Comment: @crafter the tblfollowers.follower_id =$test and events.id_user = $test is in the where clause

Comment: doh! disregard. I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: I cannot see why it's slow. The explain lists very low number of rows being involved. Perhaps your MySQL instance is resource constraint, check `my.cnf` and up the memory limits.

Comment: @Steven Firstly, you will need to add the actual SQL running in the DB without any PHP variable. Those `render_table` statements might be messing things up. Secondly, you should add your schema and indexes information (if any). Thirdly, you should explain the schema. Finally, you should explain what output you're looking for

Comment: @MostyMostacho I have run the query directly against the tables without the PHP and it takes on average 10 to 12 seconds to run. Below is the table schema for both tblfollowers and events. The output I am looking for is any events for id_user = 50 and any events where follower_id in tblfollowers = id_user in events and username in tblfollowers = 50.

Comment: @MostyMostacho TblFollowers:
username int(11) No None Browse distinct values  Change  Drop  Primary  Unique  Index Fulltext
follower_id int(11)No None Browse distinct values Change Drop  Primary  Unique  Index Fulltext
timestamp timestamp No CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @MostyMostacho events: event_id int(11) No None AUTO_INCREMENT  Browse distinct values  Change  Drop  Primary Unique  Index Fulltext event_name varchar(400) utf8_general_ci No None  Browse distinct values Change Drop Primary Unique Index Fulltext
id_user int(11) No None Browse distinct values Change Drop  Primary  Unique  Index Fulltext
start_date datetime No None Browse distinct values Change  Drop Primary Unique  Index Fulltext
timestamp timestamp on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP No CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Browse distinct values Change  Drop  Primary  Unique  Index Fulltext

Comment: @Steven: Nobody can read that.  Please go back and edit the question and paste your tables into the question.

Comment: @AndyLester I updated in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclose: I don't know PHP.

However, try to split up the query and put it back together using `UNION`. I think it's the `OR` that's killing your performance, by preventing the use of your index. Here's what I think your query will look like outside of PHP.

```
SELECT event_id
     , start_date
     , end_date
     , event_name
     , details 
  FROM events
  LEFT JOIN tblfollowers 
    ON events.id_user = tblfollowers.username 
 WHERE events.status ='active' 
   AND tblfollowers.follower_id = '$test'
UNION
SELECT event_id
     , start_date
     , end_date
     , event_name
     , details 
  FROM events
 WHERE id_user = '$test'
```

Comment: WOW! That definitely fixed the problem. Now I have to figure out how to incorporate what you did into the PHP file. Went from 10 seconds to .0283 seconds.  Thanks a bunch!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need only two fields in your `group by` (and if the field `event_id` is the primary key you only need **that** field.
Having group by to consider less fields should make your query faster.
You should only put **functionally independent fields** in the group by, listing functionally dependent fields there is non-nonsensical and a waste of time.
Fortunately MySQL does not require you to do this.

```
$scheduler->render_table("events  
   LEFT JOIN tblfollowers ON events.id_user = tblfollowers.username 
   WHERE events.status ='active' 
     AND '$test' IN (tblfollowers.follower_id, events.id_user) <<-- maybe faster
   GROUP BY events.event_id, events.id_user   <<-- only include unique key fields
   ORDER BY events.timestamp DESC"
,"event_id","start_date, start_date,event_name,details");
$scheduler->render_sql("SELECT event_id, start_date, end_date, event_name, details 
                        FROM events ");
```

See here for more info: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

**Why is it slow?**
Without the table definitions for tblfollowers and events it's hard to tell.

**Use explain**
If you want to see where the bottleneck is, put an `EXPLAIN` in front of the select and paste the outcome in your question.

```
$scheduler->render_sql("EXPLAIN SELECT event_id, start_date, end_date, event_name, details 
                        FROM events ");
```

**Tacking on indexes does not help**
Use the output from `explain` to inform your decisions, adding indexes slows down your inserts and updates, and bloats your disk usage.

Comment: both tables have int(11) for username, follower_id, and id_user in events.  The query still runs slow so im not sure what the deal is aside from volume. But the volume is not so great that i would expect the delay.

Comment: Sound like harddisk failure to be. A broken sector can slow a query down from sub second to hours. Try moving the setup to another computer or harddisk.

Comment: And put in that explain. Stop fantasizing about the problem and start measuring.

Comment: this is what I got from Explain:

Comment: 1 SIMPLE events ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 1593 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 SIMPLE tblfollowers ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 dbhappps.events.id_user 17 Using where; Using index

Comment: It looks like the explain for the actual query. It lists both `events` and `tblfollowers`.

Answer (score 1):

This is primarily a temporary file that slows down your query. The word `temporary` in `EXPLAIN` means that every time you run this query MySQL server has to create a temporary table. While it's small, it is held in memory and thus is relatively fast. When it becomes large enough, it is moved to the disk and makes the query run really slow.

When is temporary table used? It is well described in the [MySQL Reference Manual – Optimizing Database Structure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html). In your case, it must be happening because you're ordering by field `timestamp` which is not included into the `GROUP BY` clause.

Next, do you really need to group by all of these fields? Since you're grouping by primary key of `events` table, grouping by another `event`'s fields would have no sense. Try executing this query:

```
$scheduler->render_table("events 
    LEFT JOIN tblfollowers ON events.id_user = tblfollowers.username 
    WHERE events.status = 'active' 
    AND tblfollowers.follower_id = '$test'
    OR events.id_user = '$test'
    GROUP BY events.event_id, events.timestamp 
    ORDER BY events.timestamp DESC"
, "event_id", "start_date, start_date, event_name, details");
```

**EDIT:** By the way, didn't you forget to put the parentheses around the condition? `AND` takes precedence over `OR`.

```
WHERE events.status ='active' 
      AND (tblfollowers.follower_id='$test' OR events.id_user='$test')
```

That way it seems more logical to me.

Comment: ok well none of this seems to be working so maybe i can explain what i am trying to accomplish with the query.  These problems started when I added 1,500 followers to the table tblfollowers. I am trying to get all events posted by id_user 50 in events as well as any events that follower_id 50 follows in tblfollowers.

Comment: it is in parenthesis in my original example.

Comment: Try adding an `INDEX` on `timestamp` field - it is necessary to avoid temporary table. By the way, how long does the query run? 1593x17 rows mustn't be too much even for on-disk filesort...

Comment: its around 3 seconds which doesnt seem long but it is when you see white space for that long

Comment: it takes around 5 seconds I just ran it again a few times

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without the create table statements.

For that group by and order by.
If event_id is not a primary you may see some improvement by adding a composite index on  event_id, timestamp desc.  If ordering by event_id, timestamp desc is acceptable that would save you some time.  Group does an implicit order by so reordering will slow things down.  Grouping by event_id, timestamp ASC then ordering by timestamp DESC may approach a worst case scenario for that ordering.

If event_id is primary, adding a index on timestamp DESC will create a composite index of event_id and timstamp DESC.